# odd sql error, variable not being recognized correctly

Tags: mysql, variables, select

I'm currently in hour two of this issue, I can't explain it so I will simply show what is going on. I don't know if this matters at all, but I am using the linkedIN API to retrieve a user's linkedIn unique ID.

In English, what I'm doing:

1. User Signs in with LinkedIn
2. I read-in user's LinkedIn ID (returned from the API)
3. If ID exists in database, say "hello", if not, show them a form to register

**The issue I am having:**

The following line works and properly returns the `1` user I have in the database with a linkedIn ID of `OtOgMaJ2NM`

```
$company_data = "SELECT * FROM s_user WHERE `LI_id` = 'OtOgMaJ2NM'";
```

The following query returns no results - using the same database with the same record in the table `s_user`:

```
$linkedIn_id = "<?js= id ?>";
echo $linkedIn_id;
```

The following code outputs `OtOgMaJ2NM` with no trailing spaces.

So far so good ... expcept when I run the query this time using the variable, no records are returned!

```
$company_data = "SELECT * FROM s_user WHERE `LI_id` = '$linkedIn_id'";
```

Further notes:
When I `echo` `$company_data` the same query is displayed when I use the variable as did when I used the plain text version of the query.

Anyone have ANY ideas?

Thanks,

Evan

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that when echoing variables it strips the tags, so when you're using it with the query you're actually saying:

```
$company_data = "SELECT * FROM s_user WHERE `LI_id` = '<?js= OtOgMaJ2NM ?>'";
```

I could be wrong, but have you tried stripping the tags from the variable?

Comment: so what would you suggest writing for the query then? I'm slightly confused by your answer, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you send the variable between the "", the MySQL engine will search for $linkedIn_id literally and not for its content.
Seems you are using php, but I'm not sure about the right syntax. Take a look in the docs.

Comment: if that's the case then why when I echo the query does it return the correct info?

Comment: Because in echo, the interpreter parses the string before pass it to the server.

Comment: So how can I possibly fit this into the sql?

Comment: Try to concatenate the query string with the variable.